# screen size issue after suspend if hdmi removed before wakeup

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, suspend, hdmi

I'm using an extra monitor on HDMI. If I unplug the hdmi while the laptop is running the size of my build-in display is fine.
If I unplug the hdmi cable while the laptop is suspended, when I wake it up I can move the mouse to the left beyond my screen limit.
My external monitor is bigger than the built in one, so I believe the screen does't update to the new smaller size of the built in display.

If I restart the laptop then everything works fine.

How can I solve this issue?

Running ubuntu 22.04 on Xorg.

Comment: I just found the solution. In settings display select single display instead of join monitors.

Comment: If you’ve solved it, consider posting your solution as an answer?